# Push the return value into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function inside a loop that changes it's returned value in each iteration and I want to save all the returning value of the function in an array.

What's wrong with this code:

```
function riddle() {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a.push(function() {
            return i * i;
        });
    }
    return a;}

// code to test your solution: 

var a = riddle();
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { b.push(a[i]()); }
console.log(b);
```

This what supposed to be printed:

`[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`

But instead I get this:

`[100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]`

Comment: I'm certain that if you searched for "JavaScript functions in a loop", you'd have found many answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's wrong with this code?

The variable `i` is hoisted to the top of the scope within the function `riddle`. The anonymous functions generated in the array do indeed close over the local variable `i`. But the last value of `i` is 10, so all of them return 100.

By the way, this code will create a truly local variable to the inner function, and perform as you intended.

```
a.push((
    function(tmp) {
        return function() {
            return tmp*tmp;
        };
})(i));
```